# log4Net with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, log4net

I have an asp.net application using log4Net to log messages to a file.
I would like to log messages to a database knowing that I am using code first with entity framework.
I am currently able to log message to database and file at the same time if the database already exists.
However what I would like to achieve, is that if the database hasn't been created yet then the first call to log a message to database would both create the database and log the message.
I can do this now by calling this code in global.asax.cs file:

```
using (var DataContext = new MyContext())
        {

            Log logsnew = DataContext.Logs.SingleOrDefault();                
        }

        logger.Info("info test message");
```

This is the constructor of my context:

```
public MyContext()
        : base($"name=MyConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
    }
```

I would like to avoid the using block each time I have to log a message, is there another way to do this please?

Comment: move logging configuration into your DbContext Class.

Comment: Could you explain futher? my log4net configuration is in my web.cong file. I also have a class representing the log table related to my context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want log4net to log to the database and file, just configure a FileAppender and an AdoNetAppender. You should not log into your application database, best practice is to make a separate database for your logging. If you have problems with your database, you can still log into your logging database.

Comment: That makes sense, but it's not what they want.
My current problem is that Executing the code above, creates the database if it doesn't exist in the first place but doesn't log the message afterwards. Connecting to database is not allowed via log4net in the first place.
However, if the database already exists, then i am able to log anything from log4net. Is there a way to be able to create the database but release the lock on it right afterwards so that log4net can log messages?